# Even after providing proper path in the program , I can not open the file in Visual C++

Tags: c, file

I have written a simple C code in visual C++
I am planning to open a text file for reading , but whenever i enter path it shows "unable to open the file".
then i hardcoded the path in the program itself. still same error , can anyone tell me what I am doing worng ? or where I wil have to copy paste that file so that i can open it in visual c++ through my code ?
here is my code :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
int main(){
  FILE *p;
  char file1[20];
  char ch,i;   
  printf("\nEnter the source file name to be copied:");
  gets(file1);
  p=fopen(file1,"r");  // I have tried changing it with actual path to the file

  if(p==NULL)
         {
      printf("cannot open %s",file1);getch();
      exit(0);
         }
   while((i=getc(q))!=EOF)
   printf("%c",i);
   fclose(p);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try `if (p == NULL) { perror("filename"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }`

Comment: Have you tried to use `\\\` or '/' instead of '\' in the file path. Otherwise it might consider '\' as an escape sequence?

Comment: sorry guys, I have corrected typo , with "file1" also I get same error

Comment: @IvayloPetrov
it worked with \\ , yes , only that was the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save one file in your directory where you have saved the program.
And try it typing the perfect full name of the file including format of the file. 
Your code seems error free. 
When you're telling directory during execution use // only dont use / otherwise it will show you error and file won't open.

Comment: it worked with double slash in the path for the file , with single it does not work

Answer (score 0):

it worked after Entering double back slash "\\" instead of single back slash after the Drive name (example "c:\\") for the path to the file.